# vsftpd passive mode 227

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vsftpd

На клиенте при переходе в пассивный режим не могу получить список файлов. Вылезает надпись 227 .... (На скрине видно) и через некоторое время выдает operation timed out. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?
Ubuntu, сервер vsftpd

Содержимое файла /etc/vsftpd.conf:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Причиной может быть известный баг с IPV6, попробуйте добавить 
     `listen_ipv6=NO`
перед 
    `listen=YES`

Comment: Попробовал так сделать
Теперь пишет "Connection refused"